# Loading gz file with pig and storing it into HBase with COMPRESSION => 'GZ'

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I have log files compressed with gzip. 
Currently I load .gz file with pig, parse the log with REGEXP and store the result into the HBase table. The table has option COMPRESSION => 'GZ'.
But I'm wondering if it is best way. Obviously .gz files are smaller, but does how pig read separate rows? Is it unzipping it? Wouldn't it be more efficient to unzip it before loading?

Can anyoneone give me any hint?

Regards
pawel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pig basically consists of a compiler which produces sequence of mapreduce jobs for you pig program. 
How does pig understand gzipped file :- 
your mapreduce job , started by pig script, **looks at the file extension to see what type of compression codec it was used to compress and calls the relevant decompressor**.
 Hadoop first checks all the codecs installed and will report an error if it cant find the codec required for your file. 
So, `yes it unzips it and then RecordReader reads the unzipped file as one record per line by default`.
And this is the reason of heap size error in some mapreduce job as mapred child cant get enough space to keep the uncompressed data.
  `In hbase, Compression is applied on columnfamily level in the table to reduce the space taken , and also to send less data over wire in case of scan`. Also, there are only 3 types of compression supported in hbase - gzip, lzo and snappy and all of these have unique ids which should not be changed.

Comment: Chandra kant, thanks for your answer. In you opinion - is there any point in unzipping files before loading? I've made a test - files in .gz format have 7.2GB, unzipped - 90GB. And .gz loads in 1h, unzipped in 1h20min. I'm curious what is the reason, that unzipped files load longer...

Comment: I think you misunderstand the function of load operation. It's not like that you say load file.fz as (..) and pig immediately loads it to memory. When you write a pig script with load and then store function, pig creates a mapreduce logical plan with map and reduce jobs as per your pig script . And then fires up a mapreduce job. Until you write a store or dump function , your load function is meaningless. So, unzipping part is done as part of the mapreduce job by hadoop. And unzipped files take longer, because of network io . Their size is bigger, so they take more io over the wire.

Comment: I do understand it as you said. But I'm wondering if it's better to unzip it before loading to shorten time of script execution or leave unzipping for MapReduce task created by pig script.

Comment: If you don't have memory restrictions, then it's ok to unzip it. However, CPU overhead to unzip it by hadoop is minimal and optimized according to data blocks structure. This is especially true if you want to zip or unzip hfiles of hbase. Unless you are trying to play with it, you can do it manually , but if you want a stable system, don't do it  and let hadoop handle it .